# Plots' names based on original CSV files' names

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have some csv files and I need to produce the same plot from each one of them. I have read the csv files in R as dataframes and put them together in a list, and each element of the list is named after the original file.

**Question**

How do I title the plots based on each csv file's name? I am new to both ggplot and regex functions.

This is what I have tried; first I create some toy dataframes to "mimic" the original data and put them in a list:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create four dataframes

df1_09 <- data.frame(
  first_column = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  second_column = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
)

df1_10 <- data.frame(
  first_column = c(4, 2, 3, 1),
  second_column = c(8, 6, 7, 5)
)

df2_09 <- data.frame(
  first_column = c(9, 10, 11, 12),
  second_column = c(13, 14, 15, 16)
)

df2_10 <- data.frame(
  first_column = c(12, 10, 11, 9),
  second_column = c(16, 14, 15, 13)
)

list_of_df <- list(df1_09, df1_10, df2_09, df2_10)
```

Now I create the function that I will use to plot the dataframes. I would like the name of the dataframe as main title. So I have tried:

```r
# Create plot function

plot_data <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = data[, 1], y = data[, 2])) +
    xlim(0, 12) +
    ylim(5, 16) +
    ggtitle(paste(names(data))) +
    xlab("x axis") +
    ylab("y axis") +
    theme_bw()
}

myplots <- list()
myplots <- lapply(list_of_df, plot_data)
```

The code works, but if I check the list's structure I get the weirdest output ever (I just pasted a small part of the output below)

```r
str(myplots)
#> List of 4
#>  $ df1_09:List of 9
#>   ..$ data       :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ first_column : num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
#>   .. ..$ second_column: num [1:4] 5 6 7 8
#>   ..$ layers     :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ :Classes 'LayerInstance', 'Layer', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class LayerInstance, Layer, gg>
#>     aes_params: list
#>     compute_aesthetics: function
#>     compute_geom_1: function
#>     compute_geom_2: function
#>     compute_position: function
#>     compute_statistic: function
#>     data: waiver
#>     draw_geom: function
#>     finish_statistics: function
```

In addition, if I check the first plot I can see it has picked the column name, not the dataframe's name:

```r
myplots[[1]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tibble)

# Create list and keep object names as name
L <- tibble::lst(df1_09, df1_10, df2_09, df2_10)

myplots <- lapply( 1:length(L), function(i) {
  ggplot(L[[i]]) +
    geom_point(aes(x = first_column, y = second_column)) +
    xlim(0, 12) +
    ylim(5, 16) +
    ggtitle(names(L)[i]) +
    xlab("x axis") +
    ylab("y axis") +
    theme_bw()
})

myplots[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my real data, I am reading the data from a folder; each csv file is converted into a dataframe and put in a list, `list_of_df`. I can't go from that structure to a tibble like in your example. I have tried `new_tibble <- tibble(grp = unlist(list_of_df))` but it does not work.

Comment: possible approach: pass the filenames to a list using `list.files()`, use `basename()` for naming, and read the file using `lapply()` with a function like above, but with reading added.

Answer (score 2):

Same logic as @Wimpel but if you are into `tidyverse` using `imap` maybe helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- function(data, name) {
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = data[[1]], y = data[[2]])) +
    xlim(0, 12) +
    ylim(5, 16) +
    ggtitle(name) +
    xlab("x axis") +
    ylab("y axis") +
    theme_bw()
}

list_of_df <- lst(df1_09, df1_10, df2_09, df2_10)

result <- imap(list_of_df, plot_data)
```

Comment: Thank you, I get a weird warning message though: `Use of data[[1]] is discouraged. Use .data[[1]] instead.` In addition, I don't understand how the function can pick up the dataframe name. I see in the function call a variable called `name`, but when you use `imap` it is not passed. It that a syntax typical of `imap`?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore that warning or try with `.data[[1]]` and `.data[[2]]` instead and yes, this syntax is specific to `imap`. `imap` by default passes data and name as two arguments to the function. Name is the name of the list, if name is not present it passes index instead.